# How to get rid of a strip of background-color appearing over a picture element inside an anchor on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I use the `picture` element to render dark- and light-mode versions of a couple of icons on my site.

These pictures happen to be inside an anchor element so that I can make them, along with text captions, clickable links.

```
<a href="https://github.com/Antrikshy">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="/path/to/github-mark-dark.png" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
    <source srcset="/path/to/github-mark-light.png" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
    <img src="/path/to/github-mark-dark.png">
  </picture>
  <br/>
  <small>More on GitHub</small>
</a>
```

When I tried to style links across my site like so...

```
a:hover {
  background-color: var(--brand-color-2);
  color: var(--main-background-color);
}
```

... it caused these `picture` elements to render with small strips of background color across them, *when the link is hovered over*.

[image: Sample 1]
[image: Sample 2]

Of course, I only want the text to receive those styles on hover.

I absolutely cannot seem to get rid of that strip. I did notice that setting `picture { font-size: 0; }` seems to shift the lines up slightly, but they remain the same size.

Comment: How can I debug the code? There's no enough code to replicate the output or the issue.

Comment: Do you have a link to your website or a demo where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: There is enough code; I just didn't have images. Here's a playground I put together: https://jsfiddle.net/0Ly6nqfu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the unwanted strips use this CSS (i.e. be specific that you want only the text to have a changed background color on hover)

```
a:hover small {
  background-color: var(--brand-color-2);
  color: var(--main-background-color);
}
```

Otherwise transparent bits of your pictures are getting the background color too.

---

Update, as this is not suitable because if wanting to style links across the whole site, another method of preventing transparent bits showing background color has to be found.

The simplest seems to be to set

```
a picture { background-color: white; }
```

although for better generality across a whole site use a CSS variable instead of a fixed color or be more specific if different color backgrounds are used.

Comment: I could, but I'm trying to style all links across the whole site.

Comment: You need to do something as your images look as though they have transparent bits. I’ve added another suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I could make that work since I have the background color in a variable at all times. I ended up going with different styling but I’ll keep this in mind!